# Cypher query to find all the email sent and receive my a user in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have following graph created in neo4j.

```
(user1)-(:EMAIL_SENT)->(email)-[:EMAIL_TO)->(user2)
(user1)<-(:EMAIL_TO)-(email)<-[:EMAIL_SENT)-(user2)
(user1)-(:EMAIL_SENT)->(email)-[:EMAIL_TO)->(user3)
```

Here user1 has sent two email and received one email. I want to build a query to retrieve all the email sent and received by user1 plus information of other users who sent and received emails from user1

I have this query but it is only showing emails received. I would like it to extend it to include email sent as well. Not sure how to do that

```
 OPTIONAL MATCH (you:User)<-[:EMAIL_TO]-(Email),
          (they:User)-[:EMAIL_SENT]->(Email)
 WHERE you.username = user1
 RETURN Email.text AS text, 
        Email.subject AS subject, 
        Email.id AS message_id, 
        they.username AS emailfrom, 
        you.username AS loggedinuser
```

Comment: Please write the relationships with [] instead of ().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option - two different ways.

1) Use [`union`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-union.html) to query combination:

```
MATCH (U:User {username:'user1'})-[:EMAIL_SENT]->(E:email)-[:EMAIL_TO]->(R:User)
RETURN E.text as text, 
       E.subject as subject, 
       id(E) as message_id, 
       U.username as emailfrom, 
       R.username as emailto
UNION
MATCH (U:User {username:'user1'})<-[:EMAIL_TO]-(E:email)<-[:EMAIL_SENT]-(R:User)
RETURN E.text as text, 
       E.subject as subject, 
       id(E) as message_id, 
       R.username as emailfrom, 
       U.username as emailto
```

2) Determine the direction of the email based on the type of relationship:

```
MATCH (U:User {username:'user1'})
        -[L:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO]-(E:email)-[R:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO]-
      (P:User) 
      WHERE type(L)<>type(R)
RETURN E.text as text, 
       E.subject as subject, 
       id(E) as message_id, 
       U.username as user, 
       P.username as participator, 
       (CASE type(L) WHEN 'EMAIL_SENT' THEN 'out' ELSE 'in' END) as direction
```

Comment: one question. Above query work perfectly, but I want to modify it further to have something like facebook messaging results i.e show latest message per participator(either sent or receive) . Is it possible to achieve that with Cypher query ?

Comment: @jas Yes this is possible: you must first sort the e-mails by timestamp in descending order, then group by the participants and then use the `collect` to retrieve all e-mails to specific participants.

Comment: I tried --- MATCH (U:User {username:'user2'})
        -[L:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO|REPLY_TO|REPLY_SENT]-(E:Email)-[R:EMAIL_SENT|EMAIL_TO|REPLY_TO|REPLY_SENT]-
      (P:User) 
      WHERE type(L)<>type(R)
RETURN E.text as text, 
       E.subject as subject, 
    E.timestamp as time,
       id(E) as message_id, 
       U.username as user, 
       P.username as participator, 
       (CASE type(L) WHEN 'EMAIL_SENT' THEN 'out' ELSE 'in' END) as direction
ORDER BY E.timestamp DESC,collect (E.text) ---- but I get error

Comment: Cannot use aggregation in ORDER BY if there are no aggregate expressions in the preceding RETURN (line 5, column 1 (offset: 187))
"RETURN E.text as text, ". Also, you mention group by - do you mean count ?

Comment: @jas Not a good idea to ask questions in the comments. If you have a new question, it is best if you open a new topic.